# Code sign error from apple free account libswiftCore.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I want to test my swift Test project in my iPhone device but when I am compiling it is showing below error. My code sign in configuration is right, please have a look of attachment.
"libswiftCore.dylib: errSecInternalComponent"

No additional target is added and same code sign in identity is added i project setting also.

***OS : 10.15
XCode: 11.3.1***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set the `Code Signing Identity` in both target and Project ?

Comment: I have not added any additional target and same code sign in identity is added in Project also.

Comment: Try this. Quit Xcode, go to Derived Data folder and delete its contents. Clear Trash. Now open the Xcode and try to run the same project in phone.